# SwiftUI 2.0 How can I do an overlay over a rectangle

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have been rebuilding my old UIKit app and creating in Swiftui 2.0 (IOS 14) . I have 3 Text labels and underneath that there is supposed to be a divider . There should also be an overlay above that divider to show text has been clicked . If you see my SwiftUI image below my only issue is getting that Blue Overlay section to appear directly above the Divider like I did in UIKit . As you can see from the image right now that Blue Overlay is about 2 or 3 px above the divider . Any suggestions would be great . This is the code

```
VStack {
  HStack {
            Text("Following")
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(hexString: "5C5C5F")))
                .font(.system(size: 16))
            Spacer()
            Text("Followers")
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(hexString: "5C5C5F")))
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .font(.system(size: 16))
            Spacer()
            Text("Profile")
                .overlay(
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 80, height: 3).offset(y: 10)
                    , alignment: .bottom)
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(hexString: BlueOcean)))
                .font(.system(size: 16))
            
        }.padding(20)
        Rectangle().frame(height: 3)
            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))

}
```

This is what it looks like in SwiftUI

[image]

This is how it is supposed to look: UIKit

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach - the idea is to apply underline to each tab and just align them as needed (style of each can be tuned, of course)

Prepared with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoTabsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
            TabItemView { Text("Following") }
            TabItemView { Spacer() }
            TabItemView { Text("Followers") }
            TabItemView { Spacer() }
            TabItemView(selected: true) { Text("Profile") }
        }
    }
}

struct TabItemView<Label: View>: View {
    var selected = false
    let label: () -> Label
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            label()
                .font(.system(size: 16))
                .foregroundColor(selected ? Color.blue : Color.black)
            Rectangle().frame(height: 3)
                .foregroundColor(selected ? Color.blue : Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
        }.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked thanks, it is exactly what was needed .